# Web API 2 Basic Authentication and allow actions not marked [Authorize]

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, restful-authentication

I have been looking at Basic Authentication in Web Api2 and don’t seem to find an explanation for something I am confused about.

I created a web api application project with individual authentication in Visual studio 2017.

I have the default code

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{ 
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
     }

    public string Get(int id)
    {
       return "value";
     }
}
```

I call these actions via postman, browser etc all good.

If I add the [Authorize] attribute to one of the methods I get 401 unauthorized response as expected.

So far so good.

I then add basic authentication by creating a class derived from AuthorizationFilterAttribute

```
public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
    var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

    if (authHeader != null)
    {
      var authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
      var decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
      var usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
      var userName = usernamePasswordArray[0];
      var password = usernamePasswordArray[1];

      var isValid = userName == "ade" && password == "password";

      if (isValid)
      {
        var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), null);

        HttpContext.Current.User = principal;

        return;
       }
     }
    }

    HandleUnathorized(actionContext);
  }

 private static void HandleUnathorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
 {
    actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
    actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Scheme='Data' location = 'http://localhost:");
 }
```

I register the filter in WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
```

I use postman to call the action marked with [Authorize] and send with header Authorization: Basic YWRlOnBhc3N3b3Jk

The request is authorized and I get my action response. All good.

Now I call the action that is not marked with [Authorize] without a Authorization header from postman expecting to get a response but the OnAuthorization is called and obviously returns HandleUnathorized(actionContext); I only expected the OnAuthorization method to be called where an action is marked with [Authorize]

So now I am thinking what is the point of the [Authorize] attribute because OnAuthorization is called regardless so what is the point of marking actions [Authorize] attribute?

Secondly, I added the following method to my class

```
private static bool SkipAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        Contract.Assert(actionContext != null);

        return actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any()
                   || actionContext.ControllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<AllowAnonymousAttribute>().Any();
}
```

I call this method at the beginning of OnAuthorization

```
if (SkipAuthorization(actionContext)) return;
```

If I mark my actions with [AllowAnonymous] it works.

If there is no [Authorize] attribute on the controller or specific actions then surely the OnAuthorization should also be skipped?

I just don't see the point of using [Authorize], I am clearly missing something here, am I doing something wrong or do I need to mark the actions with [AllowAnonymous] to exclude them.

Comment: you added a global filter here  - config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute()); -. which means every request will run through your action filter.

Comment: If I comment out the line config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute() the method OnAuthorization is never called. I marked an action with [Authorize] and [BasicAuthentication] I get 401 Unauthorized everytime.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **[Authorize]** attribute and windows authentication, then authorization will done automatically, you don't need to do any special configuration, but any special case if you need to override **[Authorize]** class then your class is like below,

1. Instead of inheriting **AuthorizationFilterAttribute**, you can
   inherit **AuthorizeAttribute**

   ```
       public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
       {
        //your override methods
       }
   ```
2. Instead of using **[Authorize]** attribute, use your derived class name. In your case use **[BasicAuthenticationAttribute]**, not **[Authorize]**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Fran you set me off on the right path.

I commented out the following line

```
config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
```

I used the following attributes in controller

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{ 
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    [Authorize]
    [BasicAuthentication]
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
}
```

If I called the action get() I got a response, OnAuthorisation was not called.
If I call get(int id) I get 401 Unauthorised and OnAuthorisation is not called.

I removed the [Authorize] from get(int id) action

```
[BasicAuthentication]
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "value";
}
```

and it all worked, OnAuthorisation was called as expected.

Comment: Authorize is the built in authentication action filter.  So if you are using windows authentication or identity and you don't have any special requirements, you can use [Authorize].  So you've got a specific example, you need to read a token, you need to derive from it and override the OnAuthorization method